how I can implement custom filter for datatable with angularjs?
Need to fetch row, with rank 50
Expecting to get right method in above section
this.dtOptions = {
  ajax:
  {
    url: this.apiHost+'/stock/list',
    dataSrc: 'apiData',
    processData: true
  },
  rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
    if(data['rank'] > 50){
      
    }
  },

